# Bubble Sort — Strings outputting integers

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

I can't get my second bubble sort to print out strings, it will only output 0's and 1's.

Excuse my lack of programming skills and ugly code—but I really can't get it working even though I tried the solutions recommended in other threads with ***strcmp*** and putting the * ***before char declaration***.

The objective of the algorithm is to output first a couple of integers in one order, then reverse it. The same goes for the characters, which is where I'm stuck.

**Bubble sort for characters:**

```
  // Print (unsorted) CHAR in-values
  printf ("\n\nin:  ");
  for (cc = 0; cc <= 10; cc++) {
      printf ("%d", datastring[cc]);
  }

  // Sort CHAR out-values
  printf ("\n out: ");

  lengthcc = sizeof(datastring) / sizeof(char);

  for (cc = 0; cc < lengthcc; ++cc) {

    for (dd = 1; dd < lengthcc; ++dd) {

            if (datastring[dd] < datastring[dd - 1]) {

                tmpcc = datastring[dd];
                datastring[dd] = datastring[dd - 1];
                datastring[dd - 1] = tmpcc;

            }

    }

  }

  // Print (sorted) CHAR out-values
  for (cc = 0; cc < lengthcc; ++cc) {

    printf ("%d", datastring[cc]);

  }
```

**Beginning of the code—declarations and sort for ints**

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int ii, jj, cc, length, lengthcc, dd;

  int data[] = { 7, 4, 3 };
  char datastring[10] = { "o", "i", "u", "f", "O", "I", "w", "U", "W", "B", "F" };
  int tmp;
  char tmpcc;

  // Print first arguments
  printf ("%s %s %s \n \n", argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);

  // Print (unsorted) INT in-values
  printf ("in:  ");
  for (ii = 0; ii <= 2; ii++) {
      printf ("%d", data[ii]);
  }

  // Sort INT out-values
  printf ("\n out: ");

  length = sizeof(data) / sizeof(int);

  for (ii = 0; ii < length; ++ii) {

    for (jj = 1; jj < length; ++jj) {

            if (data[jj] < data[jj - 1]) {

                tmp = data[jj];
                data[jj] = data[jj - 1];
                data[jj - 1] = tmp;

            }

    }

  }

  // Print (sorted) INT out-values
  for (ii = 0; ii < length; ++ii) {

    printf ("%d", data[ii]);

  }
```

So sorry for the messy code and bad presentation.

Comment: 1) `"o"` Use single quote　--> `'o'` 2) `char datastring[10]` --> `char datastring[11]` 3) `printf ("%d", datastring[cc]);` --> `printf ("%c", datastring[cc]);`

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the complete code including the #include lines? Slicing a fragment does not help.

Comment: When your prof said 'don't use single-letter variable names', s/he meant 'use meaningful ones', not 'ii', 'jj' :(

Comment: IMHO, `i`, `j` and `c` and fine variable names for the purpose of this assignment.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I'm very aware that my code sucks, but it's actually the assignment that used 'ii' and 'jj' from the beginning—so I just stuck with it throughout.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char datastring[12] = { 'o', 'i', 'u', 'f', 'O', 'I', 'w', 'U', 'W', 'B', 'F' , '\0'} ;
   int c, d, buffer, lengthc ;

   // Print (unsorted) CHAR in-values
   printf ("\n\nin:  ") ;

   for (c = 0; c < 12; c++)
   {
      printf ("%c", datastring[c]) ;
   }

   // Sort CHAR out-values
   printf ("\n out: ") ;

   lengthc = sizeof(datastring) / sizeof(char) ;

   for (c = 0; c < lengthc; ++c)
   {
      for (d = 1; d < lengthc; ++d)
      {
         if (datastring[d] < datastring[d - 1])
         {
             buffer = datastring[d] ;
             datastring[d] = datastring[d - 1] ;
             datastring[d - 1] = buffer ;
         }
      }
   }

   // Print (sorted) CHAR out-values
   for (c = 0; c < lengthc; ++c)
   {
      printf ("%c", datastring[c]) ;
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

you have to write "%c" to display characters. "%d" is used to display integers, "%f" double or float and so on.
Because the letters are arranged by the ascii table it does not work very well with uppercase letters.
If you want to initialize single characters in a string you have to use single qoute. the length of the string was too short, too.
And please change your code style. Why do you use variables like "dd" and not "d"?